# Removing active class from button

Tags: javascript

I have 3 buttons that represent a product category on my site. I want to load the page with the "All Products" button having an active class and then have that class removed and added to another button when clicked. There seems to be an issue that is causing an active class to be added twice to a button or not removed and so two buttons will be active at the same time.
[Two active buttons at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L3Ox.png) and [Active class added twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5x5W.png)

I can fix the problem if I remove the active class from the "All Products" button but again I want the page to load with it set to active. These buttons also have to control the visibility of elements depending on what category they belong to.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="list-group" id="myBtnContainer">
        <button class="btn list-group-item active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">All Products</button>
        <button class="btn list-group-item" onclick="filterSelection('shirts')">Shirts</button>
        <button class="btn list-group-item" onclick="filterSelection('pants')">Pants</button>
      </div>
```

HTML - Example Element:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 filterDiv shirts">
              <div class="card h-100 ">
                <a href="product.html"><img class="card-img-top" src="blackshirt.png" alt=""></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a href="product.html" class="product-title">Black Shirt</a>
                  </h4>
                  <h5>$24.99</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <a href="product.html" class="btn btn-success view-btn" role="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View Product</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
    if (c == "all") c = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
      if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
  }

  function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
    }
  }

  function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
        arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
      }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
  }

  // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
  var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
  var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      this.className += " active";
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why are you tagging your question with jquery if you're not using jquery?

Comment: Besides, your code is working on my side. https://jsfiddle.net/931d5c1L/

Comment: Your code is working well removing this `onclick="filterSelection(..)` from your elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Two active buttons at once**

  > Check the logic within this function `filterSelection`.
- **Active class added twice**

  > You can use `toggle` function from the `classList` attribute.
- Show products according to the selected button

  > - Use the `data` attributes and work with the `classList` attribute.
  > - I.e: Set to your buttons: `data-target='shirts'`, `data-target='pants'` and so on.
  > - Use a class `hide` with this style: `display: none`

```js
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].classList.toggle('active');
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    
    var target = this.dataset.target;
    filterSelection(target);
  });
}

function filterSelection(target) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.filterDiv').forEach((div) => {
    if (target === 'all' || div.classList.contains(target)) {
      div.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      div.classList.add('hide');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group" id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn list-group-item active" data-target='all'>Show all</button>
  <button class="btn list-group-item" data-target='shirts'>Shirts</button>
  <button class="btn list-group-item" data-target='pants'>Pants</button>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 filterDiv shirts">
  <div class="card h-100 ">
    <a href="product.html"><img class="card-img-top" src="blackshirt.png" alt=""></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">
        <a href="product.html" class="product-title">Black Shirt</a>
      </h4>
      <h5>$24.99</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <a href="product.html" class="btn btn-success view-btn" role="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 filterDiv pants">
  <div class="card h-100 ">
    <a href="product.html"><img class="card-img-top" src="blackshirt.png" alt=""></a>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">
        <a href="product.html" class="product-title">Pants</a>
      </h4>
      <h5>$44.99</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <a href="product.html" class="btn btn-success view-btn" role="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View Product</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Resource

- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: I added more information to my question. The solution needs to be able to filter the products and their visibility.

Comment: It seems that my navbar was messing it all up. Once I removed the active class from the nav, it worked flawlessly. Silly mistake on my part but thanks for all the help.