# the filterable element adds active class twice

Tags: javascript, filtering

I m referring to this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp

I did the exact same thing as shown on above link, but in my case the "active" class keeps adding every-time i click & doesn't remove for others also for the button i clicked as well.

Codes:

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("productdiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("controller");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}


<div class="controls" id="controller">
 <button onclick="filterSelection('all')" type="button" class=" filter-btn btn-primary btn active" style="margin:0 3px;">All</button>
<?php do{?>   
    <button id="filterbtn" onclick="filterSelection('subcategory-<?php echo $row_SubCategories['SubCategoryID']?>')" type="button" class="btn btn-primary filter-btn" style="margin:3px;"><?php echo $row_SubCategories['SubCategoryName']?></button>
<?php }while($row_SubCategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($SubCategories));?>    

</div>              


<div class="productdiv subcategory-<?php echo $row_Products['ProductSubCatID']?>"> product info.. </div>
```

Just for information, the filter works completely fine. Just the button active class is problem.

Comment: Can you paste your code here.

Comment: @Sandeep did. i also tried answer from this. yet doesn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675423/removing-active-class-from-button

Comment: `current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");`
In this line before "active" there is extra space. can you remove it and try.

Comment: @Sandeep did as replace("active", ""); no changes

Comment: i can share link on private if its possible here.

Comment: Sure. You can message me directly. Also I am assuming that you are waiting for DOM to render before your script runs.

Comment: @Sandeep u got the link?

Comment: Hi, change this line from `var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");` to `var current = 
 document.querySelectorAll(".btn.active")`

Comment: thank you so much @Sandeep. works smooth.